# EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink --- Meteor Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, npm

I am new to meteor and I get errors especially installing npm and running the meteor command. I got rid of all the errors at the install part, but now whenever I run the meteor command on powershell I get this error:

> EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\users\userName\desktop\project-name\packages\rocketchat-google-vision.npm\package-new-66a0vd.nnlae\node_modules'

I can not access the localhost:3000.